# Remove all comments in Python 3 lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I have a XML file that previously I commented some elements, and now I want to uncomment them..

I have this structure

```
<parent parId="22" attr="Alpha">
 <!--<reg regId="1">
  <cont>There is some content</cont><cont2 attr1="val">Another content</cont2>
 </reg>
--></parent>
<parent parId="23" attr="Alpha">
 <reg regId="1">
  <cont>There is more content</cont><cont2 attr1="noval">Morecont</cont2>
 </reg>
</parent>
<parent parId="24" attr="Alpha">
 <!--<reg regId="1">
  <cont>There is some content</cont><cont2 attr1="val">Another content</cont2>
 </reg>
--></parent>
```

I would like to uncomment all the comments of the file. That consequentially, also are the commented  element and I would to uncomment them.

I am able to find the elements that are comment using xpath. Here is my snippet of code.

```
def unhide_element():
    path = r'path_to_file\file.xml'
    xml_parser = et.parse(path)
    comments = root.xpath('//comment')
    for c in comments:
       print('Comment: ', c)
       parent_comment = c.getparent()
       parent_comment.replace(c,'')
       tree = et.ElementTree(root)
       tree.write(new_file)
```

However, the replace is not working as it expects another element.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is missing a crucial bit of creating the new XML element from comment text. There are a few other bugs related to the incorrect XPath query, and to saving the output file multiple times inside the loop.

Also, it appears that you are mixing `xml.etree` with `lxml.etree`. As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), the former ignores comments when the XML file is parsed, so the best way to go is to use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de).

After fixing all of the above we get something like this.

```
import lxml.etree as ET


def unhide_element():
    path = r'test.xml'
    root = ET.parse(path)
    comments = root.xpath('//comment()')
    for c in comments:
        print('Comment: ', c)
        parent_comment = c.getparent()
        parent_comment.remove(c)  # skip this if you want to retain the comment
        new_elem = ET.XML(c.text)  # this bit creates the new element from comment text
        parent_comment.addnext(new_elem)

    root.write(r'new_file.xml')
```

Comment: Great, this worked. However, I don't know why my lxml version does not work without using the getroot() first. I cannot work directly in the ElementTree with parse.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you want to uncomment everything, all you really need to do is remove each "< !--" and "-->":

```
import re

new_xml = ''.join(re.split('<!--|-->', xml))
```

Or:

```
new_xml = xml.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
```